# How to quantify the 'completeness' of a basis set?

Tags: linear-algebra

As far as I know, a set of functions/vectors is complete or it is not. In many fields incomplete sets are used to approximate functions/vectors.

I understand that given two sets of different functions, each set may be more suited for one or another case. But, if linearly independent functions are added to a set, more functions can be obtained by spanning the whole set. In such sense, the whole set is 'more complete'.

Is there any quantity that represents the 'degree of completeness'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there's many ways to quantify the completeness of a basis set.

But an example that makes most sense to me is this:
If a complete basis would contain N linearly independent vectors, you could quantify the completeness as a percentage of N. If you have N linearly independent basis vectors, you have 100% completeness. If you have N/2 linearly independent basis vectors you have 50% completeness. If you have 3N/4 linearly independent basis vectors you have 75% completeness.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for answer. Certainly the proposed procedure assign a number which has desirable values in the limiting cases (eg. N=N implies 100%), although I am unsure of its usefulness. 
For example, given a subset of two L.I. vectors (which span a 2D space) the procedure returns $\approx 67%$ of completeness for a 3D space which may  sounds deceptive. If the interest vector space is infinite dimensional, every basis set used in practice would be rated with 0% completeness. In some sense this sounds right, but I am not sure of its usefulness.
Finally, as the cardinality of

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^m$ equals the one of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This makes me harder to visualize the issue.

Comment: I fully agree with many of your points, but I don't know of any other way to describe the quality of a basis set. I think for each specific problem, the quality of the basis set may have its own measure. For example if you want the energy of Hamiltonian, then the basis set quality can be measured by the quality of the energy. However again this can get complicated: lower energy doesn't always mean better. You can say "the lower the energy the better the basis set", but we all know that Dunning basis sets are not optimized to give the lowest energy for a given number of parameters, they are...

Comment: meant to extrapolate well for energy *differences*. So then your desired measure (for quality fo a basis set), is not "how low of an energy does the basis set give", but "how good are the energy differences when compared to experiment". So there's different ways to evaluate the quality of the basis set depending on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I completely agree. I was thinking in terms of space coverage. Something like minimizing some distance between every possible vectors at least in some region of the space.